# More idiomatic "if-else" replacement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've seemingly simple problem, based on condition e.g. that value in dataframe is smaller than two, change value to 1, in opposite case to 0. Kind of "if-else".

Toy exmample, input:

```
   a   b
0  1  -5
1  2   0
2  3  10
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
```

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [-5, 0, 10]})

arr = np.where(df < 2, 1, 0)
df_fin = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

I don't like direct dependency on `numpy` and it also a little looks verbose to me. Could it be done in more cleaner, idiomatic way?

Comment: pandas is dependent on numpy though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General solutions:**

Pandas is built in numpy, so in my opinion only need import. Here is possible set values in `df[:]`

```
import numpy as np

df[:] = np.where(df < 2, 1, 0)
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
```

A bit overcomplicated if use only pandas functions:

```
m = df < 2
df = df.mask(m, 1).where(m, 0)
```

**Replace to `0,1` solution:**

Convert mask for map `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` by [`DataFrame.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.view.html) or like in another answer:

```
df = (df < 2).view('i1')
```

Comment: `df = (df < 2).astype(int)`?

Comment: In second way there should be `df = df.mask(m, 1).where(m, 0)`. I really like `df[:]` trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pandas' replace might be handy here:

```py
 df.lt(2).replace({False : 0, True: 1})
Out[7]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
```

or you just convert the booleans to integers:

```py
df.lt(2).astype(int)
Out[9]:
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  0
```

Comment: I've noticed that for my purpose, with python truthiness I don't even have to cast to `int`. Thanks!